# Crop images (Freeware)

Tags: gratis, images, offline

I'm looking for a program focused on cropping images with presets.
I have multiple images in multiple resolutions. I need to crop an area of 300x500 in positions that are not constant and save the cropped images.
Irfanview does that but it takes too many steps to do so.
Similar to these, but offline:

- http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs
- http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ImageResizeCropCanvas

Comment: Franck, you are fairly active on S.O, so I will assume that you can code. If you don't get an answer, perhaps you can automate the procedure with Ifranview? I can **highly** recommend AutoIt for automating Windows programs. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I program scripts, not software. My last resource will be automate the process with AutoIt.

Comment: Well, AutoIt is a scripting language & fairly simple. I realize this isn’t an answer, but I don't actually know an answer. Keep this in line as a last resort. If you ever do write a single AutoIt script, you are unlikely to stop there, as it is so useful. Good luck on your hunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Freeware and lossless crop.
http://www.vieas.com/en/software/jcropper.html
Super lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) convert or mogrify depending if you need to output to another directory or modify in place.

As it can be called from the command line you can simply batch up the crops with the positions.

See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) for crop examples.

ImageMagick is:

- Free *gratis*
- Cross platform including Windows/Linux & Max OS-X.
- Very quick and powerful.
- Great for automating image operations.

Comment: ImageMagick is great! In fact I use it with my scripts a long time. However, I need a program where I can see the image and use the mouse to crop a predefined area (keeping aspect ratio) as the images resolutions and cropping position may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably reasonably simply add a [python plug-in](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) to [GIMP](http://gimp.org) that would add a layer with your 30x500 frame in it, move the frame to where it is desired and then a second script use the position of the "frame" to crop the original image and export it.

- Free
- Allows you to position the frame where you need it
- Once you have the script written it will be a 3 step process per photo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to crop image with presets on Windows operating system, try this software named as [***SIMP***](http://sourceforge.net/projects/photoresizer/) which is an open source utility and having **features** such as *drag & drop, presets with dimension, zoom and dynamic aspect ratio calculation, etc.*

If you are looking for the software cropping images for Mac OS then try the ***“Acorn”*** which is a **Mac OS X 10.8 & 10.9** picture and image editor. This can help you to crop an image within **few steps**. To get more information about ***Acorn*** image cropping tool visit this link:

**http://www.flyingmeat.com/acorn/**

Comment: This one gets very close to what I need. But it won't allow user defined cropping presets.